# how to read and deserialize json array from Post Request in C# Web Method

Tags: c#, arrays, json, webmethod

I have Developed the C# Web Method. In this Method Request and Response are Json Array Format.

When I Read Json Array from Post Request, Error Occurred.

My Json Array is

```
[{"partner_hotel_code": "510","reservation_id": "7660"},{"partner_hotel_code": "510","reservation_id": "7666"}]
```

Error is

```
"Type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' is not supported for deserialization of an array."
```

When i changed the Json into below mentioned format, My method is working Properly.

```
{"JsonData":[{"partner_hotel_code": "510","reservation_id": "7660"},{"partner_hotel_code": "510","reservation_id": "7666"}]}
```

But I don't want this format.

Please help, how to rectify the Problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can map that JSON array to List of C# class.

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string partner_hotel_code { get; set; }
    public string reservation_id { get; set; }
}
```

In the web method add parameter `List<RootObject> ObjectList`

Comment: Hi Jerry, I can't add Parameters for the Web Method. Because of The Third Party Call this function like **booking_sync()** and not like **booking_sync(List<RootObject> ObjectList)**

Comment: if it's parameterless then how are you getting jsonarray

Comment: also add that method to the question

Comment: Below is my code
`[WebMethod]
    public void booking_sync()
    {
        string postData = new System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var dictionary = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>[]>(postData);}`

Comment: in this case deserialize postdata to list<rootobject> using newtonsoft library

Comment: I guess you can use JavaScriptSerializer also

Comment: How to deserialize this postdata

Comment: var list = jss.Deserialize<list<rootObject>>(postData); //or see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the Json parameter is required to be an object of **key-value pairs**, that is:

> {"JsonData":[{"partner_hotel_code": "510","reservation_id":
>   "7660"},{"partner_hotel_code": "510","reservation_id": "7666"}]}
>
> {'Key': Value} => Key - JsonData, Value => array of items

With this in mind, you can make your models to match this structure as follows:
Prepare a model Item,

```
public class Item
{
    public string partner_hotel_code { get; set; }
    public string reservation_id { get; set; }
}
```

Then prepare a root 'Node' object that will take in a list of the items, let's call it Reservations:

```
 public class Reservations
    {
       List<Item> JsonData { get; set; }
    }
```

You can then deserialize as shown below:

```
var data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Reservations>(postData);
```

But the structure you wanted is something like: `[{"partner_hotel_code": "510",...}]`

You can achieve this by many ways, an example is using a foreach:

```
var list = new List<Item>();

foreach(var item in data.JsonData)
{
  list.Add(item);
}

/*The value of list here will contain the items*/

listArray[] myArray = list.ToArray();
```

Comment: Hi Felix,
For Testing Purpose, I have manually send the Json Array Using Postman Rest Client. At this time the web method is not triggered. Only error response is coming. The Error message posted above.

Comment: Did you try to make the changes I outlined above? You must send the array in the format `{"JsonData":[{"partner_hotel_code": "510",...]` because it has to be a key-value pair. Without a key-value pair, you'll get the error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

another solution to this problem is to serialize your array first, then create a JSON object with your method parameter name, and Serialize that...
it goes something like this

```
var myobj = { myArray: JSON.stringify(a) };
passedData = JSON.stringify(myobj);
$.ajax({
        type: "POST", contentType: "application/json", data: passedData,
        url: window.location.href + "/myMethod",
        success: function (result) {
           ....
        }
});
```

and the webMethod

```
public static void myMethod(String myArray)
{
   dynamic jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myArray);
   for (var i = 0; i < jsonResponse.Count; i++)
   {
       ...........
   }
}
```